# Route constraints: raising exception when there's no match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

Given a Rails route constraint like this:

```
class UserConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    User.where(code: request.path_parameters[:code]).any?
  end
end
```

This won't work because of a subroute.

**routes.rb**:

```
constraints UserConstraint.new do
  get ':code', to: 'documents#index', as: :documents
  get ':code/*slug', to: 'documents#show', as: :document
end
```

It just returns the following:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
Couldn't find User with 'slug'={:code=>"show"}
```

Is this only solvable with more constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer for something similar this is how I solved it.

If you have globbed routes like I did it's way easier to write separate constraints for them.

**routes.rb**

```
constraints UserConstraint.new do
  get ':code', to: 'documents#index', as: :documents
end

constraints SlugConstraint.new do
  get ':code/*slug', to: 'documents#show', as: :document
end
```

**user_constraint.rb**

```
class UserConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    result = User.where(code: request.path_parameters[:code]).any?
    raise Errors::NoCode, 'User not found' unless result

    result
  end
end
```

**slug_constraint.rb**

```
class SlugConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    slug = "#{request.path_parameters[:code]}/#{request.path_parameters[:slug]}"
    result = Document.where(slug: slug).any?
    raise Errors::NoDocumentSlug, 'Document not found' unless result

    result
  end
end
```